# Как сделать задержку окончания анимации

Tags: java, android, android-animation, objectanimator

Есть анимация которая проигрывается 1500 миллисекунд. К этой анимации я добавил `AnimatorListener` и теперь каким то образом хочу сделать отсрочку вызова метода `AnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd` скажем на 1000 миллисекунд. В общем, мне нужно что то типа `setStartDelay()` , только по окончанию анимации.

```
    ValueAnimator countAnim = new ValueAnimator().ofInt(mTotalCount);
    countAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            tvCount.setText(""+ animation.getAnimatedValue() );
        }
    });
    countAnim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            //do something
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    countAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(0.5f));
    countAnim.setStartDelay(1000);
    countAnim.setDuration(1500);
    countAnim.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
},1000 /*длительность задержки в мс*/ );
```

Comment: Да, работает! Спасибо!